# Passing Outlook Mail Item Argument to Function

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I'm writing a sub that generates emails and attaches both PDF receipts and (depending upon the client) excel receipts for business done during the day.  Since not every firm receives an excel receipt, but every firm receives a PDF receipt;

I was building separate functions that handle these operations.

**Problem: Passing an already created outlook Mail item to a function**

**Error message received:User-defined type not defined**

**Location: The error occurs in the private sub at the bottom of the code posted.** `Private Sub BuildPDFConfirmEmail(ByRef outMail As olMailItem, ByVal firmName1 As String, ByVal firmName2 As String, ByVal firmName3 As String, ByVal isTraderSeparate As Boolean)`

**The Code currently inside the `BuildPDFConfirmEmail` is merely dummy code for testing until I could get it working**

```
Option Explicit

Private Const EMAIL_BODY As String = "Hello," & "<br><br>" & "Please find today's trade confirmation(s) attached.  Thank you." & "<br><br>" & "Best Regards," & "<br>"
Private Const PDF_FILE_PATH As String = "X:\Back Office\Confirm Drop File\"
Private Const EXCEL_CONFIRM_FILE_PATH As String = "X:\Back Office\Confirm Drop File\Excel Confirm Drop File\"

Public Sub SendPdfConfirmEmails()
'Sends PDF confirm emails to clients
'Version 2

    Dim appOutLook As outLook.Application
    Dim outMail As outLook.MailItem
    Dim eeBook As Workbook
    Dim reportsByFirmSheet As Worksheet, controlPanelSheet As Worksheet, tradesMasterSheet As Worksheet
    Dim firmAlreadyRun As Boolean, isTraderSeparate As Boolean, firmNeedExcelConfirm As Boolean
    Dim activeWorkbookName As String, currentFirmName As String, currentTraderName As String, firmEmail As String, firmName1 As String, firmName2 As String, firmName3 As String, formattedReportDate As String
    Dim lastRowReportsByFirmSheet As Long, lRowContactsMasterSheet As Long, reportsByFirmRowCounter As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    activeWorkbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outMail = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set eeBook = Workbooks(activeWorkbookName)
    Set reportsByFirmSheet = eeBook.Sheets("ReportsbyFirm")
    Set controlPanelSheet = eeBook.Sheets("Control Panel")
    Set tradesMasterSheet = eeBook.Sheets("Trades Master List")

    'Sets Date parameters in Reports by firm and ensures date linkage between reports by firm and control panel by running control panel routine
    reportsByFirmSheet.Cells(1, 2) = controlPanelSheet.Cells(7, 6)
    reportsByFirmSheet.Cells(2, 2) = controlPanelSheet.Cells(7, 6)
    formattedReportDate = Replace(Format(Range("printinvdate"), "m/d/yy"), "/", ".")

    'Call gen_report

    'finds last row to create end bound of for loop iteration through Reports By Firm Sheet
    lastRowReportsByFirmSheet = reportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Iterates through reports by firm and steps down each row to capture all firms and generate emails
    For reportsByFirmRowCounter = 11 To lastRowReportsByFirmSheet

        currentFirmName = reportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 5).Value
        currentTraderName = reportsByFirmSheet.Cells(reportsByFirmRowCounter, 6).Value

        'Tests to see if firm was already run and subsequently if the emp was already run if annotated that emp is seperate in memory manager area
        firmAlreadyRun = FirmDidRun(currentFirmName, currentTraderName)

        'Skips iteration process and moves to next if firm/trader has already been run
        If firmAlreadyRun = True Then GoTo skipIteration

        firmEmail = GetFirmEmailInfo(currentFirmName, currentTraderName, isTraderSeparate, firmNeedExcelConfirm, firmName1, firmName2, firmName3)

        'tests firmEmail for clients who do not receive emailed confirms
        If firmEmail = "NO" Then GoTo skipIteration

        'Creates new email object
        Set outMail = appOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        Call BuildPDFConfirmEmail(outMail, firmName1, firmName2, firmName3, isTraderSeparate)

skipIteration:

    Next

End Sub
Private Sub BuildPDFConfirmEmail(ByRef outMail As olMailItem, ByVal firmName1 As String, ByVal firmName2 As String, ByVal firmName3 As String, ByVal isTraderSeparate As Boolean)

With outMail
.Display
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: change `ByRef outMail As olMailItem` to `ByRef outMail As MailItem`

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks very much @ScottHoltzman

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I posted your comment answer, to close the question-if you would like to post one. I will happily delete my answer

Comment: @Om3r - this question should really be closed since it's a simple typographical error and doesn't really assist future users. Please see the close reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Scott Holtzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1569536/scott-holtzman)

Change **`ByRef outMail As olMailItem to ByRef outMail As MailItem`**

Comment: Assuming the answer does not reveal the question should be closed, (This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error), if the resolver declines a request to post the comment as an answer  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments  "Post an answer with the solution in the comments, and make it Community Wiki by checking the Community Wiki box." as well 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins

Comment: @Tyop - since you recognize that the question should be closed for the reason you mentioned, it would be great to add a close vote for that reason.

Comment: @Scott Question has been flagged.

Comment: Okay I can't delete now. I have flagged as well

Comment: @Tyop - if you all just VTC it will get closed with 2 more votes (including yours).